# How to split string Arraylist Hashmap?

Tags: android, string, list, split

I get a string which looks like this

```
["{action= some text, task= some text}", "{action= some text 2, task= some text 2 }" ]
```

how do I extract the content of action and task and store it in two seperate string?
(E.g String action and String task)

Comment: sure its not like  `[{"action":"sometask"`

Comment: nope. the value above is what I get from getting the string saved in arraylist hashmap. I wanted to extract the string, but I couldn't come up with a correct code :(

Comment: that looks like a json. can you post what you have tried

Comment: I tried to parse it as jason array, but the values are invalid.

Comment: it should look like  `[{"action":"sometask"` and post your code. If its a string you can use split by `=` or use regex to extract the content. make sure whether its a json or not

Comment: That's not JSON. It's the string representation of a java `Map` object inside a java `ArrayList` object - and there's no easy way to parse that string without lots of `.substring()` statements or a complicated regex pattern.

Comment: do you know any way how to parse it?

Comment: @user3325919 post your code by editing your question

Comment: Manually is the only way. Iterate through the characters looking for delimiters, choose the substring after that index to the next index, etc. Or a complicated regex pattern. I can't do it for you though.

Comment: oh okay,thanks anyways.

Answer (score -1):

If you are the Creator of this input `String`, I don't ever recommend this way of storing data. **JSON** is the best solution for you. No need to generate a complex `REGEX` that for sure will not be generic enough to accept your future edits

`JSON` is the enhanced way of storing files in a way of **Parameter, Value** data. You can simply create a `JSON` object and use its simple way of adding data data e.g. `objectJSON.put("key", "value")`. It is very similar to Object oriented, but with an external feature that is exporting your `JSON` object as a string file

Here is a good [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/) of how to use JSON and parse them.