# Split string into two separate variables

Tags: android, string, split

I have this code:

```
    String a = "{action= some text, task= some text}, {action= some text2, task= some text2}";
    String[] b = a.split("\\{action\\=|\\,|\\}|task\\=");  
    for( String z : b){
        Log.e("eto", z);
    }
```

How do I store the text after "action=" which is some text to String action? same with task?

Comment: I would not typically recommend Regular Expressions, but I think this is one of those cases where they would be quite useful. Unfortunately I don't have time to type out some proper (working) code, so I'll leave this as a comment for now. If it's not enough to get you started, I might post a full answer later.

Comment: duplication of same question by same user. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125308/how-to-split-string-arraylist-hashmap

Comment: @CompuChip ok I will wait for your response :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html). Example included in link.

EDIT: You may need to use a couple of them, first one for comma separation than other for equals.